# advice to manage properly NSURLSession

Tags: ios, asynchronous, download, nsurlsession, background-thread

i begin to developp an iphone application and i need some advice about the NSURLSession and about how to manage properly the download and parsing of my data.

i just finish to correct a bug for the download of my data in a nsurlsession, but regarding how difficult i find to understand these asynchronus request, i think my solution is not really good...
also the download bug appear with 2 different solution of download, wich make me think that i forgot to do something...

In, my project i download different xml files (and some zip files with pictures sometime) that i need to parse before to display their informations. these informations can change quickly so i want to download them again if i load my page again.
i was looking for an easy way to manage all the downloads in the same way, like that i wouldn't have to re write a lot of code.

i found this [project](https://github.com/ncipollina/nsurlsession-sample) first.

With that , i just had to use that code to manage the downloads :

```
NSString *downloadUrl = @"https://www.url.com";

        NSURL *location = [NSURL URLWithString:downloadUrl];
        // DownloadManager  is my version of the CTSessionOperation of the github project
        DownloadManager *operation = [DownloadManager new];
        operation.downloadUrl = downloadUrl;
        operation.completionAction = ^(NSURL *xmlUrl, BOOL success){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (success){
                    regions = [[TeamChoiceManager sharedManager] parseRegions:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
                    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                }
            });
        };
        operation.isBackground = YES;

       [operation enqueueOperation];
```

this code works perfectly the first time i download. but if i try to launch again the download, the download is not lauched (so no error, just, this code download once and that's all).

i correct this bug by modifying the metod `(NSURLSession *)session` in `CTSessionOperation` / `DownloadManager`. i put in comment the "dispatch_once" to make it works, but i don't think that it's the good solution...

i tried an other solution wich led to the same bug. i manage the download with this code :

```
     NSString *regionsUrl= @"url";

            NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig =
            [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
// My solution to the bug          
/*NSURLSessionConfiguration *backgroundConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration
                                                                  backgroundSessionConfiguration:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.captech.mysupersession.BackgroundSession%d",numBGSession]]; */
            //   numBGSession++; this is a static NSInteger


NSURLSession *session =
        [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:backgroundConfiguration
                                      delegate:teamChoiceDetailViewController
                                 delegateQueue:nil];

        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *sessDLTask =
        [session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:regionsUrl]];

        [sessDLTask resume];
```

and in the delegate :

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
     downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.regions = [[TeamChoiceManager sharedManager] parseRegions:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

with this solution, i avoid the bug by creating a custom `NSURLSessionConfiguration` every time i try to download.

so here we go. i'm quite confuse with this 2 solutions. i don't know if they are proper way to manage the download, i don't think i correct the bug correctly, and i must have missed something with the logic of `NSURLSession`.

do you have any advice to improve these solutions or do you see one wich is much better than the other?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : if someone is looking for a more generic solution to manage networks transactions easily and properly, you can check [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which do some magic (plus you can find a lot of tutorials).

i gave up on developping something wich work for every case (especially if it's a background session because i don't need it).
in the end i just created a class with a static session, wich manage the delegates for the download, and a block that i use in didFinishDownloadingToURL to manage the downloaded data. 
certainly not perfect but good enough for the moment.

```
    typedef void (^CTCompletionBlock)(NSURL *location, NSError* err);

    @interface DownloadManager :  NSObject <NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLSessionDownloadTask *dlTask;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *location;
    @property (strong) CTCompletionBlock afterDLBlock;

    + (DownloadManager *)sharedManager;
    -(void)downloadTask;
    @end


    //
    //  DownloadManager.m
    //  MVCTest
    //
    //  Created by 
    //

    #import "DownloadManager.h"
    #import "AppDelegate.h"


    static DownloadManager *instance = nil;
    static NSURLSession *session = nil;

    @implementation DownloadManager

    + (DownloadManager *)sharedManager {
        if (instance == nil) {
            //session = [DownloadManager sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
            instance = [DownloadManager new];
        }
        return instance;
    }

    + (id)new
    {
        return [[self alloc] init];
    }
    - (id)init{
        self = [super init];
        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
        return self;
    }

    -(void)downloadTask{
        self.dlTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.location]];
        [self.dlTask resume];
    }

    #pragma mark - NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate
    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {

 NSError *error;
        if (self.afterDLBlock){
            self.afterDLBlock(location, error);
        }

    }

//i still have to manage the delegate...
    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {}

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes {}

    #pragma mark - NSURLSessionTaskDelegate

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {}

    -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didBecomeInvalidWithError:(NSError *)error{}

    #pragma mark - NSURLSessionDelegate

    - (void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session {}

    @end
```

with this class, i just need to write this code to manage the data downloaded :

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
NSString *downloadUrl = @"http://www.whatyouwant.com";
[DownloadManager sharedManager].location = downloadUrl;
[DownloadManager sharedManager].afterDLBlock = ^(NSURL *location, NSError *error) {
        weakSelf.regions = [[TeamChoiceManager sharedManager] parseRegions:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf.activityViewIndicator stopAnimating];
            [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
        });
};
[[DownloadManager sharedManager] downloadTask];
```

i still have to manage the errors and the delegate but with taht solution i will not have a lot of code to write to download some data

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

1. If you use background `NSURLSession`, be aware that this can be slower than a standard `NSURLSession`. And, if you're doing a lot of downloads, your session could be backlogged with some of the previous requests, so when you come back, it would appear to not do anything (when in fact, it's likely just busy trying to complete the prior task requests which are trying to update a table view instance that doesn't exist or isn't visible any more). This could explain why creating a new session appears to work properly (because the new session wouldn't queue new tasks behind previously enqueued tasks, but rather run them in parallel).

   I would suggest:

   - restoring the `dispatch_once` logic (because your intuitions here are right; you definitely don't want to be making a bunch of sessions, leaving the old ones out there running); and
   - when you return to this view controller, cancel any pending requests before initiating new ones.
2. Your initial attempt, using `completionAction`, is problematic because:

   - You are retaining the view controller. So instead of:

     ```
     operation.completionAction = ^(NSURL *xmlUrl, BOOL success){
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if (success){
                 regions = [[TeamChoiceManager sharedManager] parseRegions:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
                 [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:YES];
             }
         });
     };
     ```

     You might want:

     ```
     typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
     operation.completionAction = ^(NSURL *xmlUrl, BOOL success){
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if (success){
                 regions = [[TeamChoiceManager sharedManager] parseRegions:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
                 [weakSelf.tableView reloadData]; // don't need that `performSelectorOnMainThread` call
             }
         });
     };
     ```
   - You're also trying to use this `completionAction` in conjunction with a background `NSURLSession`. Note that if the app is terminated, while the download will finish in the background, this completion block will be lost (defeating the purpose in doing a background session).

     If you really need to use background sessions, you should move any logic inside this `completionAction` into the download delegate method itself. You cannot use this `completionAction` in conjunction with background sessions and expect it to survive the termination of the app (even though the `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` objects would).

---

Below is my original answer, in which I inveighed against the `CTSessionOperation` class, because (a) there is a cognitive dissonance in using completion blocks in conjunction with background `NSURLSession` (since those blocks will be lost if the app is terminated, even though the downloads will continue); and (b) it's using a non-concurrent `NSOperation` for an asynchronous task, defeating many of the key benefits of using `NSOperation`-based implementation. While both of these points are certainly problematic, I think these concerns are secondary to my points above, but I'll keep this here for reference.

Original answer:

What do you mean by "works perfectly the first time i download; but [not] if I try to launch again"? Are you talking about the app is terminated and downloads still happening in the background? The original `CTSessionOperation` would not appear to handle that correctly, because it's attempting to use the standard trick of `NSOperation` and completion blocks, but all of that is incompatible with `NSURLSession` background sessions that proceed even after the app is terminated. Once an app is terminated, the `NSURLSession` background requests continue to proceed, but all of the operations and completion blocks will be totally lost. I think this `CTSessionOperation` has missed the mark here. You really cannot enjoy the richness of background sessions that progress even after an app is terminated and expect to preserve the operations and completion blocks you created when you first launched the background download tasks. You have to stick with `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` objects and use the delegate methods only; no completion blocks or operations.

Despite my criticism of what appear to be structural flaws of `CTSessionOperation`, the attempted remedy of commenting out the `dispatch_once` and creating unique background sessions or creating standard foreground sessions is definitely *not* the right approach if you need background downloads. If anything, if you're trying to remedy the problems that `CTSessionOperation` doesn't handle background sessions after the app is terminated, this is actually going in the wrong direction, methinks.

So, the question is whether you really want to enjoy the full functionality of background `NSURLSession` (in which case you have to abandon the completion blocks and operation pattern of `CTSessionOperation`), or whether you are ok with a non-background `NSURLSession` where the downloads being terminated when the app, itself, terminates, and you only want to be able to restart them from scratch when the user fires up the app again.

Comment: thanks for your answer. By works perfectly fine, i mean for exemple, if i use this code in the viewDidLoad of a tableViewController, i will have my tableView full of data the first time, but if i go in an other view and load again the tableView, it will be empty (when enqueueOperation is lauching again, it doesn't launch the download).

Comment: I use NSURLSession just because i don't want to have the app freezing when i download. So i suppose the 2nd solution should be enough for me. But i still find weird that creating a different NSURLSessionConfiguration correct the bug, it doesn't seems logical to me.

Comment: @user3282167 I agree its curious that creating a new session works. What I can imagine is that by re-using old session, the new requests are probably queued up behind a backlog of pending downloads from the initial attempt. So I suspect the right answer is to cancel the prior requests, not to create a new session with a whole other set of requests. See my revised answer.

Comment: @user3282167 I took another look at this `CTSessionOperation` class (I was going to issue a pull request to fix some of the more obvious problems), but I'm not at all sure it can be salvaged. In addition to the litany of issues I list above, more egregiously it is specifying the _session's_ delegate to be a particular operation object. That's a complete non-starter.

Comment: thanks to your observations, i see that i've done only half of the job for the moment (normal if it doesn't work properly!). i will check how to follow and manage all the background download that i launch (delete them from the pending queue when i need). And i will post my solution once i have something good enough.

Comment: ok, it took me all this morning for fully understand your answer (as i said i have some difficulties to understand how works these asynchronous request...). So, in both of my solutions, i was creating more and more NSURLSession without finishing them wich is not the best. However, for the CTSessionOperation, even with finishTaskAndInvalidate and canceling the NSoperation, the NSOperation is never Dequeue and i don't know why...). Anyway, i'm not sur that creating and finishing NSURLSession is the best solution. Maybe i just need 1 session and to create different downloadTask.

Comment: @user3282167 The reason that `CTSessionOperation` never dequeues the operation is that they're using the operation as the delegate for the session (yikes!). That's wrong for a myriad of other reasons, too. The intent of this operation-based NSURLSession wrapper is a noble one, but the implementation is (with no offense to the authors; they didn't proclaim this to be a world-class framework, just some random sample they threw together) simply unsalvageable.

Comment: And if you _really_ need a background session, then using an operation-based approach is a complete non-starter anyway (the purpose of background sessions is that they run even after your app terminates, but blocks and operations don't survive the termination of an app). But yes, you want one session and multiple download tasks, presumably canceling the prior ones when you initiate a new one, so they don't get backlogged. If you don't need background session, you can do a more elegant operation-based implementation, but even then, the implementation isn't trivial.